# Inverse of a matrix obtained by doubling every entry in column 1

Tags: linear-algebra

Let B0 be the matrix obtained from B by doubling every entry in column 1 of B. Explain
how could we obtain the inverse of B0 from the inverse of B.

I know the answer of the inverse of B0 = the inverse of B with half of row 1. However, I do not know how to show or explain it. Can anyone give me some hints on it?

Comment: Try writing $B_0$ in terms of $B$ using a matrix multiplication i.e. $B_0=AB$ or $BA$ for some matrix $A$. What is $B_0^{-1}$ in terms of the inverses of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Then find an $A$ that works to write the new matrix in terms of a product of $A$ and $B$. (The construction is _almost_ the same as for the column case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Semiclassical gave you a great hint in the comments, it's probably a bit too hard to guess what exactly is $A$ and should you put it on the left or on the right.

So, take
$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix},$$
and observe what are $AB$ and $BA$ for $A = \operatorname{diag}(1,2,3)$, a diagonal matrix with these three numbers on the diagonal.

Of course, the above $B$ is singular and does not have the inverse, but it should give you a good idea how your $B_0$ is created.

After that, all you need is $(XY)^{-1} = Y^{-1} X^{-1}$, where $X$ and $Y$ are $A$ and $B$ in some order.